# Error! authentication failure

Tags: php, smtp

I am working on a php website,Using google smtp to send mail,The code is working fine and it is sending mail to inbox, Through google smtp.But now have changed the $username and $password,It is showing me this error,Thankyou in advance

> Error! authentication failure [SMTP: Invalid response code received
>   from server (code: 534, response: 5.7.14 Please log in via your web
>   browser and 5.7.14 then try again. 5.7.14 Learn more at 5.7.14

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 y11-v6sm11496340pfn.92 - gsmtp)]

```html
 <?php   
require_once 'Mail.php'; //this loads up PEAR Mail   
if (!class_exists('Mail')) { die('Error: The PEAR Mail class does not exist.'); }  
$host = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';  
$username = '****@gmail.com'; //replace this with your new Gmail address  
$password = '****'; //replace this with your new Gmail account password 
$port = '465';
 
$from_email = $username;
 
$from = '"california worker company" <'.$from_email.'>'; //put your name in here, but keep the double quotes
 
$to = '"california worker company" <softphoton002@gmail.com>'; //put in your name and main email address to send a test to
 
$subject = 'California Worker Lead for GENERAL CONTRACTORS';

$myname = $_REQUEST['name'];
$myemail = $_REQUEST['email'];
$myphone = $_REQUEST['phone'];
$annualpayroll = $_REQUEST['annualpayroll'];
$numberofemployees = $_REQUEST['numberofemployees'];
$yourbusinesstype = $_REQUEST['yourbusinesstype'];
$healthinsurancecarrier = $_REQUEST['healthinsurancecarrier'];
$payrollservicemethod = $_REQUEST['payrollservicemethod'];
  
$body = 'Hello Admin <br/> You get a new lead for GENERAL CONTRACTORS.<br/>
Name:'.$myname.'<br/>
Email:'.$myemail.'<br/>
Phone:'.$myphone.'<br/>
Annual Payroll:'.$annualpayroll.'<br/>
Member of Employees:'.$numberofemployees.'<br/>
Business Type:'.$yourbusinesstype.'<br/>
Health Insurance Carrier:'.$healthinsurancecarrier.'<br/>
Payroll Service Method:'.$payrollservicemethod.'<br/>';  

 
$headers = array(
  
 'From' => $from,
  
 'To' => $to,
  
 'Subject' => $subject,
  
 'Reply-To' => $from_email,
  
 'MIME-Version' => 1,
  
 'Content-type' => 'text/html;UTF-8'
  
);
  

  
$params = array(
  
 'host' => $host,
  
 'port' => $port,
  
 'auth' => true,  
 'username' => $username,
  
 'password' => $password  
);
  
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', $params);
  

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

// To user email

$headerss = array(
  
 'From' => $from,
  
 'To' => $myemail,
  
 'Subject' => $subject,
  
 'Reply-To' => $from_email,
  
 'MIME-Version' => 1,
  
 'Content-type' => 'text/html;UTF-8'
  
);
  

  
$paramss = array(
  
 'host' => $host,
  
 'port' => $port,
  
 'auth' => true,  
 'username' => $username,
  
 'password' => $password  
);
  
$smtps = Mail::factory('smtp', $paramss);
  
$bodys = 'Hello '.$myname.'<br/>
We received your message for Quote on GENERAL CONTRACTOR. We will reply you in next 24-48 hours.<br/>
Thank you';  
$mails = $smtps->send($myemail, $headerss, $bodys);



  
if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
 
 echo '<p>Error! '.$mail->getMessage().'</p>';

} else {
header("Location: http://californiaworkercomp.com/general-contractors?success=1"); 
//echo '<p>Your test message was sent successfully.</p>';
 
}
 
?>
```

Comment: I Wouldn't advise sharing login details on Stackoverflow, if you cannot get in after changing credentials, that's an account error, nothing us PHP bunnies can solve

Comment: This is not real details, its a dummy account just a refrence

Comment: Okay, thats fine, just didn't want you getting hacked. If its a log in error we cannot help you though

Comment: it is not login error, i am able to login to my gmail account,I am not able to send email by google smpt, i was able to do it first, but now that i have changed username and password iam not able to send,Please check 4th and 5th line of the code

Comment: Is it possible you have reached a Quota limit? I know google has a limit on this? how long have you not been able to send emails?

Comment: from today i changed the code,it is something to do with the php

Comment: Thankyou it is working fine now